# GWT CellTable - Column Sorting is reset after ListDataProvider refresh

Tags: gwt

I'm using a CellTable, which is fed data via a ListDataProvider.  Currently a user can sort the CellTable columns, then click a row. Clicking a row pops up a stand alone editor next to the cell table.  When the user clicks "save", the code updates the employee in the ListDataProvider, then calls:

```
listDataProvider.refresh();
```

This works, but the column sort is reset.  This is not acceptable because it resets the column sort that they have used, and it is a pain to have to resort the columns after every save.  Is there some way to tell the CellTable to keep its current column sort when refresh is called?

Comment: try `cellTable.redraw();` instead of `listDataProvider.refresh();`.

Comment: I think I tried this, but it was not showing the new data. I'll try again, and there is also a redraw method that target's a specific row. I'll try that one as well just to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, cellTable.redraw() does not work, as well as listDataProvider.flush().  Only .refresh works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adding a listener on the column sort, and sorted the list in code rather than allowing the CellTable to handle the sort.  This kept the sort order.  I'd post the code, but I no longer have access to the code base.

Answer (score 1):

Your need to call `ColumnSortEvent.fire(dataGrid, dataGrid.getColumnSortList());` if you want to recover the sort order after refresh. I think it should work the same for CellTable.

This is how we refresh the DataGrid:

```
selectionModel.clear(); // SingleSelectionModel
dataList.clear(); // List<Data>
dataList.addAll(newData); // List<Data>
dataProvider.flush(); // ListDataProvider<Data>
dataProvider.refresh();
ColumnSortEvent.fire(dataGrid, dataGrid.getColumnSortList()); // DataGrid<Data>
```